# Does Google Cloud Firewall block inter-subnet traffic by default?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, firewall, subnet, google-cloud-networking

The GCP firewall has default, implied rules to block all ingress and allow all egress. That is for external traffic, outside the VPN.

But does this block traffic *between subnets* in a single VPN by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly yes, by default traffic between subnets on a given VPC network is not allowed (except on the `default` network which is auto-created with your project).

Note that this actually blocks traffic between *all* instances, not just traffic between subnets.  So, the focus is really on the instances, not on the subnets -- but the effect will be that by default, instances on different subnets (except on the `default` network) will not be able to communicate.

Remember, VPC firewall rules are [enforced at the instance level](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#specifications), even though its configuration is at the network level.

> While the rule is enforced at the instance level, its configuration is associated with a VPC network.

As you note, there are only two [implied rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules):

- allow all egress (to any other address, including internal)
- deny all ingress (from any other address, including internal)

There are also [default rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) on the `default` network only.

- allow internal traffic (`default-allow-internal`) -- this rule allows traffic between instances (regardless of subnet)
- allow ssh ingress from any source
- allow rdp ingress from any source
- allow icmp ingress from any source

So, on a non-`default` network you would need to create the equivalent of the `default-allow-internal` rule (allow all protocols from all IPs on the network to any instance on the network).

Comment: Thank you. So if I leave the out-of-the-box setup does default-allow-internal allow traffic between subnets, or just between instances in the same subnet? Based on your answer, the latter.

Comment: It should allow traffic between all instances on the VPC network regardless of subnet

Comment: OK. So one key point (that is helping me here and that you may want to add to the answer) is that out-of-the-box, all instances can communicate even *across subnets*).

Comment: Added earlier when I responded, "regardless of subnet" :)  Happy to review an edit if something would make it clearer.  And this is only true on the `default` network that instances can communicate by default -- on other VPC networks, they cannot, and you have to add the rule.

Comment: Thank you, this has been quite helpful